# How do I position div absolute to its parent?

Tags: html, css

I tried to position div absolute to its parent. See chart1.

I set left and top properties, but the div is still positioned to root element, not its parent element dashboard.

What am I missing here, please?

```css
#nav {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

#chart1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chart2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 450px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart1">Chart 1</div>
  <div id="chart2">Chart 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: give Div parent relative

Comment: _“What am I missing here, please?”_ - absolute basics, that you could and should go read up on in any CSS beginner’s tutorial … And even just typing your question title into Google verbatim would have immediately lead you to explanations such as https://tomelliott.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent

Comment: Solved. Thank you all for your kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing `position: relative`.
parent div should have position relative and child div should have a position absolute

```css
#nav {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
#dashboard {
  position: relative;
}
#chart1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chart2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 450px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart1">Chart 1</div>
  <div id="chart2">Chart 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative` is the key.

```css
#nav {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
#dashboard {
  position: relative;
}
#chart1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chart2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 450px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart1">Chart 1</div>
  <div id="chart2">Chart 2</div>
</div>
```